# How to show in template property from array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I just try to show the value of a property in the template. But at the moment nothing is shown.

So this is the component:

```
export class ServerStatusComponent implements OnInit {
  snovieCollection: SnovietatusDto = {};

  constructor(private snovierStatus: snovieStatusService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sensorStatus
      .getSensorStatuses()
      .pipe(
        map((data) => {
        console.log(data.cameraSensors);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((status) => {      
      });
  }
}
```

And this is the template:

```
<p>Camera sensoren</p>
  <tr *ngFor="let camera of snovieStatusCollection.key|keyvalue">

    test
     <h3> {{camera | json}}</h3>

  </tr>
```

So I just want to show in the template the value of key. And the console.log returns this:

```
0: {key: "T", latestTimestamp: "2021-03-12T10:09:00Z"}
```

So I don't get any errors. But also nothing is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You aren't returning anything from the `map`. So `undefined` would be emitted to the subscription. Use `tap` for side-effects instead.
2. You aren't assigning the response to `this.sensorStatusCollection` in the subscription.

```js
export class ServerStatusComponent implements OnInit {
  sensorStatusCollection: SensorStatusDto = {};

  constructor(private sensorStatus: SensorStatusService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sensorStatus
      .getSensorStatuses()
      .pipe(
        tap((data) => {                         // <-- `tap` here
          console.log(data.cameraSensors);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((status) => {      
        this.sensorStatusCollection = status;   // <-- assign here
      });
  }
}
```

#### Update: Type

3. As pointed out by @TotallyNewb in the comments, the type of `this.sensorStatusCollection` needs to be an array of type `SensorStatusDto`

```js
export class ServerStatusComponent implements OnInit {
  sensorStatusCollection: SensorStatusDto[] = [];

  ...
}
```

Comment: This seems wrong as well. `sensorStatusCollection` seems to be of type `SensorStatusDto` and you're assigning an array to it, which will throw type mismatch. This is hard to say without looking at the `SensorStatusDto` though.

Comment: @Michael D  It works!! Thank you.I just did some changes. But he pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: I passed the wron dto. But this one is the correct one:  sensorStatusCollection: SensorStatusCollectionDto = {};